# Shopify Liquid Tag within Asset Tag

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to insert a `metafield` variable within an asset url as below:

```
{% assign review = product.metafields.review %}
{% assign key = 'rating' %}
<img src="{{ '[review.rating].png' | asset_url }}"/>
```

For some reason it isn't returning the actual variable, instead the text itself, is there a way to go about doing this?

Comment: Some more information about this would be helpful, try to include what you've tried and the language would also be very helpful. By the looks of it you are using the Django Template Language?

Comment: It's in Shopify's Liquid Language - similar to that of Jekylls

Answer (score 1):

If any reviews actually exist at the namespace product.metafields.review then you have to iterate through them. When you do that, for each iteration you'll get some key value pairs. With those you can print out the actual data of the metafield resources. What you are attempting there in your snippet seems a bit off. Try accessing the rating key in your iterator, and if it exists, the value would be available to you for your image snippet.

Comment: I just can't get it to show any variable when it's already wrapped within a liquid tag. I think it may be parsing all image asset_url's as strings?

Comment: What's happening is that the following is printed out "<img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1513/9752/t/3/assets/[review.rating].png?10386570582935712770">"

Comment: perfect! Shopify is doing exactly what it should.